# Finding a rational number which is simply normal to relatively prime bases

Tags: number-theory, number-systems, binary

Let $n\ge 2\in\mathbb Z$. Suppose that a base-$n$-decimal $(0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots)_n$ represents $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{n^k}$ where $a_{i}\in\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}\ (i=1,2,\cdots)$ is each digit number. Now, when we represent a rational number $0\lt p\lt 1$ as a base-$n$-decimal $(0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots)_n$, let's consider the following condition.

> **Condition** : For every $0\le k\le n-1$, $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{|\{i|1\le i\le N,a_{i}=k\}|}{N}=\frac 1n.$$

I've been interested in finding a rational number $0\lt p\lt 1$ which satisfies the condition for a $n$. For example, we can see $p=2/3$ satisfies the condition for $n=2$ because it is $(0.\overline{10})_2$. However, finding a $p$ which satisfies the condition for two or more $n$ seems difficult. We can see $p=21/26$ satisfies the condition for $n=2,3$ because it is $(0.1\overline{100111011000})_2$ and $(0.\overline{210})_3.$ However, I cannot find any $p$ for two $n$ other than $n=2,3$.

Then, here is my first question.

> **Question 1** : Does there exist a rational number $0\lt p\lt 1$ which satisfies the condition for two $n$ other than $n=2,3$ where the two $n$ are relatively prime?

In addition to this, the following questions seem very difficult.

> **Question 2** : Does there exist a rational number $0\lt p\lt 1$ which satisfies the condition for **three** $n$ where any two of the three $n$ are relatively prime?
>
> **Question 3** : Do there exist infinitely many rational numbers $0\lt p\lt 1$ which satisfy the condition for two $n$ where the two $n$ are relatively prime? How about the cases for three or more $n$?

Can anyone help?

**Edit** : As user level1807, who solved the question 1 and 2, points out, this is the question about the number which is [simply normal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalNumber.html) to relatively prime bases. So, the question 3, which has not been solved yet, can be said as

> **Question 3** : Do there exist infinitely many rational numbers $0\lt p\lt 1$ which are simply normal to two relatively prime bases? How about the cases for three or more bases?

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172483/on-simple-normality-to-co-prime-bases).

Comment: Is there some kind of backstory to this problem? Why is this interesting?

Comment: @level1807: Well, sadly, no backstory.

Comment: @mathlove I see. It does not even seem to me that a full investigation of the third question (i. e. proving there are infinitely many numbers) would be that hard, but without a proper motivation this is just not "fun" :) I say that as a mathematical physicist, mathematicians may disagree.

Comment: @level1807: A full investigation using Mathematica? If so, I think you can't prove there are infinitely many rationals. Mathematica, I think, can't find 'infinitely' many rationals... To prove that, I think we need a completely new way.

Comment: @mathlove of course I didn't mean Mathematica. The key is to understand how the periodic part changes when converting to a different base. And for some reason I have a feeling that once you describe the algorithm (which is well known obviously), the frequency condition will provide a way of constructing such numbers.

Comment: @level1807: Can you describe your thought more concretely? I don't think I can get your idea.

Comment: well, the thought is not very concrete anyways, sorry:) You are looking for rational numbers that are _simply normal_ to several different bases. There may be some good ideas in this huge presentation on normal numbers. http://www-2.dc.uba.ar/ccr/talks/BsAs_normality.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, let $S$ be the set of all permutations of $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. Then for each $p\in S$ put

$$x=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{m n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{p_i}{n^i}.$$

You get $n!$ rational numbers that have the desired property.For example, for $n=4$, they are

$$\frac{9}{85},\frac{2}{17},\frac{13}{85},\frac{3}{17},\frac{18}{85},\frac{19}{85},\frac{5}{17},\frac{26}{85},\frac{33}{85},\frac{36}{85},\frac{38}{85},\frac{8}{17},\frac{9}{17},\frac{47}{85},\frac{49}{85},\frac{52}{85},\frac{59}{85},\frac{12}{17},\frac{66}{85},\frac{67}{85},\frac{14}{17},\frac{72}{85},\frac{15}{17},\frac{76}{85}$$

I believe this can be easily modified by constructing sequences of $2n$, $3n$ etc. digits. Since there are new "equi-distributed" periods of length $kn$ compared to $(k-1)n$ for each $k$, there are an infinite number of such numbers for each $n$. And of course adding some random digits before the periodic part won't change anything.

Edit: here is a formula for periods of length $Mn$. Again, $p\in S$ and $S$ is the set of all permutations of $M n$ digits ($M$ copies of each digit, $p=\{p_1,\ldots,p_{Mn}\}$).

$$x=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{M m n}} \sum_{i=1}^{Mn} \frac{p_i}{n^i}.$$
For $n=2$ and $M=6$ one of the $924$ numbers given by this formula is $\frac{8}{26}$, which is  $\frac{21}{26}-\frac{1}{2}$.

Edit2: okay, so by running a simple search in Mathematica I have been able to find a ton of examples of numbers with uniform digit distributions for $n=2$ and $n=5$ simultaneously. For example, $1/66$ is the "simplest":
$$\frac{1}{66}=0.\overline{1111100000}_2 2^{-6}=0.\overline{0014213324}_5.$$
Another examples are $19/679$ for $n=3,4$; $9/142$ for $n=5,7$. For mysterious reasons there are no rationals with denominators up to $2000$ that meet the criterion for $n=4,5$.
The first (with smallest denominator) number which meets the criterion for *three* bases $n=2,3,5$ is $809/2046$:
$$\frac{809}{2046}=0.0\overline{1100101001}_2=0.1\overline{012000202022100112121102121012}_3=0.\overline{144203101322123012334420003441}_5.$$
The next for $n=2,3,5$ is $1237/2046$ (not surprisingly since these two sum up to 1). I would conjecture that this list is infinite as well (even after throwing out the ones with identical non-periodic part).

Comment: Oh, so you are only interested in those special numbers? Somehow I didn't get that from reading your post. Okay, I guess I will try to run some searches.

Comment: @barto it seems there are tons of such numbers for different pairs of relatively prime n-s.

Comment: @level1807: Nice! You solved the question 1 and 2. Mathematica is great though it should not be able to solve the question 3...